# Options for parallelizing functions on F# tree

Tags: f#, functional-programming, tree, parallel-processing

In my project, I have a data structure represented as follows:

```
type 'a Tree =
| Leaf of 'a
| Node of 'a Tree array
```

Due to the cost of traversing through large trees, I have to parallelize some following functions on this data structure:

- map
- fold
- exists (exist a node satisfying a
  predicate)
- reduce / transform (optional)

Because of nature of the problem I'm working on, number of branches at each node is varied and workloads at the leaf level are quite small. **The first question is what options should I consider for parallel execution on tree.** I'm trying to use functions from `Array.Parallel` module on every node, however, because overheads of parallelism is too big, the parallel version is even slower than the sequential version. I may change array representation to `List` or `PSeq` if it is necessary.

**The second question is how to control degree of parallelism on those functions.** I'm thinking about controlling by depth of tree, number of branches at each node, workload complexity at the leaf level and number of leaves on tree, however, combining them together seems to be complex and unpredictable.

Answer (score 4):

How about separating traversal from any other processing? Perhaps create a work queue (`MailboxProcessor` is a good starting point) and, as the tree is traversed, enqueue additional work for background processing. It doesn't solve the parallel traversal problem (which seems tricky to get right for all cases) but with additional processing relegated to the background, it should go pretty quickly. You can experiment with the number of background workers until you find a good degree of parallelism. This all assumes the amount of work to be done for each node is non-trivial.

#### EDIT

Here's some code. I'm sure it can be improved. I had to hammer it out pretty quickly. But this shows the basic concept. It only has one "background worker," i.e., the `MailboxProcessor`. I'll leave updating it to use multiple workers to the imagination.

```
type Msg<'a, 'b> =
    | Work of 'a
    | Done of 'b

type MapTransformer(f) =
    let results = ResizeArray()
    let m = MailboxProcessor.Start(fun payload ->
        let rec loop() =
            async {
                let! msg = payload.Receive()
                match msg with
                | Work work -> 
                    results.Add(f work)
                    return! loop()                
                | Done (channel : AsyncReplyChannel<_>) -> 
                    channel.Reply(results :> seq<_>)
            }
        loop())
    member this.Enqueue(item) = m.Post(Work item)
    member this.Results = m.PostAndReply(fun c -> Done c)

let uberMap tree =
    let m = MapTransformer(fun x -> x + 1)
    tree |> List.iter (fun x -> m.Enqueue(x))
    m.Results

uberMap [1; 2; 3]
//outputs [2; 3; 4]
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your suggestion. For example, with `map` function, output of the function is a tree with the same shape as input, only leaf nodes are adjusted. I don't think it is easy to separate between tree traversal and computation. Can you explain clearer how to use `MailboxProcessor` in the context of tree algorithms?

Comment: I updated the question with code. I used a `list` instead of a tree, but the concept is the same.

Comment: Nice formulation, Daniel. I still don't see similarity between `list` and `tree` here. Because `list` is flat, you can easily get result from `Transformer.Results` which is a `ResizedArray`. However, `tree` is recursive, it is not clear to me how I can obtain results; if my input is a tree `Node[| Leaf 1; Node [|Leaf 2; Leaf 3|]|]`, how it is gonna return `Node[| Leaf 2; Node [|Leaf 3; Leaf 4|]|]` (with small changes in the code).

Comment: To use this code with minimal changes, you would need to flatten the tree beforehand and un-flatten afterward. One way I could imagine doing that is emitting a pair of `node` and `parentNode` as you traverse the tree.

Answer (score 3):

`Array.Parallel` uses `System.Threading.Parallel.For`. When you call that function, it tries to find an optimal schedule for the given task. However, with a typical recursive tree algorithm, this means a lot of calls to `Parallel.For` and you probably end up with far too many threads. (Unless `Parallel.For` is optimized for that use case which I don't know.)
So I think Daniel's suggestion is a good idea if the workload per node is not too small. An alternative idea is to introduce a threshold with respect to the remaining depth of a tree as described by Stephen Toub at the end of [this blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2008/01/31/7357135.aspx?PageIndex=1).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out an interesting article. I've checked released source code of `Array.Parallel` module, they don't control degree of parallelism so it is possible to spawn too many threads. One possible way to avoid it is overriding `Array.Parallel` module using `ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism` property. The article has a nice idea of flattening the tree before doing computation, but it is only relevant with fold-like functions. I will definitely check out control parallelism by depth of a tree mentioned there.